# Anaconda and Python Shell

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am a newbie, was trying to install OpenCV, I used this video for reference-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xAslL8htuQ

And in the beginning of the video, it was said that python and numpy are prerequisites.
[image: When I tried importing numpy on Python 3.6.4 Shell]

Then I opened command prompt on my Windows 10 and typed-
pip list
[image: Numpy version 2.6.5 is installed already]

So I tried importing numpy on command prompt-
[image: Python version is 3.6.5 and importing numpy was successful. I don't understand why Anaconda, Inc is written beside the version.]

Opened jupyter notebook through Anaconda navigator-
[image: Numpy was successfully imported]

Experts, I don't understand how is Anaconda related to my command prompt. I got "Anaconda" installed on my Windows 10 in a workshop on "Data Analytics". But I don't understand that why can't I import numpy on a Python Shell/IDLE, just like I import it on my command prompt or jupyter notebook. And does pip list only show packages which I can import on command prompt and jupyter notebook but not on Python Shell? Is my Python Shell completely independent of pip list, and Anaconda? If I want to import numpy on IDLE, would I have to install it again? And as I want to learn OpenCV for image processing, should I install OpenCV using pip and then I would be able to import it on my jupyter notebook or command prompt but not on Python IDLE? Is it like Python Shell/IDLE only for normal Python programming but not for using python libraries like tensorflow/numpy/opencv for "Data Analysis"?

Please help. Would mean a lot. My doubts might be really silly because I don't have much knowledge about Anaconda and pip. Thank you.

Comment: Anaconda installs its own python executable. You now have more than 1 python sources. Your command prompt takes the python and scripts that are mentioned in your PATH as environment variables. So now you have installed numpy on anaconda's python and not on the one you installed separately. This is another reason why Virtual Environments are useful. It gets rid of most of the confusion regarding packages.

Comment: Thank a lot Ninad Gaikwad. Is it fine if I install OpenCV using pip? And what if I uninstall python IDLE/Shell? Would if effect pip and Anaconda?

Comment: You can uninstall python and idle if you want it will not affect Anaconda's python. You can install OpenCV using pip, but I remember i had to install opencv-contrib instead of opencv to get some of the methods to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do pip install opencv-contrib-python. Or you can download a pre-compiled whl file for Windows from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv).